# How to get the file name, size and mime type of a dropped file in iOS 11?

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop, ios11

I have custom class that conforms to the NSItemProviderReading protocol to get data from a dropped file.

Once the file is dropped I get an NSData object as the protocol defines:

```
(instancetype)objectWithItemProviderData:(NSData *)data 
                        typeIdentifier:(NSString *)typeIdentifier 
                                 error:(NSError * _Nullable *)outError;
```

Then how can I get the file name, file type and size from the NSData object provided?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50467943/ios-drag-drop-get-file-name-of-dropped-file/50612076#50612076).

TLDR: Use `UITableViewDropItem.dragItem.itemProvider.suggestedName` for file name. Use `typeIdentifier` in the method you mentioned for the type, and `NSData.count` for the size.