# IOS Drag& Drop get file name of dropped file

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using IOS' Drop feature to import a pdf file into my app. Is there a way to get the filename of the dropped file?

I can't find anything in `UIDropSession` or `UIDropInteraction`.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm assuming it is an external drop? What's the exact thing you are dropping? A URL of a file? Or something else?

Comment: It's an external pdf file

Answer (score 3):

In case of a `UITableView`, check out `UITableViewDropItem.dragItem.itemProvider.suggestedName`. It contains the file name without extension.

Then use `UITableViewDropCoordinator.session.loadObjects()` to load the files asynchronously and reconstruct their filenames and extensions. Extensions can be reconstructed by mapping the UTIs from `NSItemProviderReading.object()` to file extensions.

```
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, performDropWith coordinator: UITableViewDropCoordinator) {
    guard let indexPath = coordinator.destinationIndexPath else { return }

    for item in coordinator.items {
        guard let fileName = item.dragItem.itemProvider.suggestedName else { continue }

        let placeHolder = UITableViewDropPlaceholder(insertionIndexPath: indexPath, reuseIdentifier: "Placeholder", rowHeight: 44)
        placeHolder.cellUpdateHandler = { (cell) in
            // Configure cell
        }
        let context = coordinator.drop(item.dragItem, to: placeHolder)

        // Load file contents
        item.dragItem.itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: PlaylistItemReader.self) { (reader, error) in

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                guard let reader = reader as? PlaylistItemReader else {
                    context.deletePlaceholder()
                    return
                }

                // Convert file type to actual extension
                guard let fileExtension = PlaylistItem.typeToExtension[reader.fileType] else {
                    context.deletePlaceholder()
                    return
                }
                // fileExtension is something like "m4a" or "mp3"

                print("File '\(fileName).\(fileExtension)'")

                context.commitInsertion(dataSourceUpdates: { (insertionIndexPath) in
                    // update model
                })
            } // async

        } // load
    } // items
}
```

Note: `PlaylistItemReader` is my custom class that implements the `NSItemProviderReading` protocol.

Comment: Works for me. And I used __`UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass`__ (typeIdentifier as CFString, kUTTagClassFilenameExtension) to get the file extension name from UTI.

Answer (score 3):

you can get the name from `UIDropSession`, e.g. `session.items.first?.itemProvider.suggestedName`